# Insert into a table having a sub-select?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have this audit table:

```
create table audit(
    id int IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    item_id int NOT NULL,
    history text NOT NULL,
)
```

And I have this trigger:

```
create trigger tr_mytable_audit ON mytable after insert, update, delete
as
select *
from inserted as i
  full join deleted as d
    on i.id = d.id
for xml path('row'), root('rows')
```

How can I insert records in the audit table where `item_id` must be the `id` column from either `inserted` or `deleted` and the `history` column should contain the xml for that particular record.

Comment: What xml?   Is there an xml column in mytable?

Comment: @TabAlleman The xml string should go in the `history` column.

Answer (score 0):

So you mean this?:

```
create trigger tr_mytable_audit ON mytable after insert, update, delete
as
INSERT INTO audit(item_id, history)
SELECT i1.id, (
 select *
 from inserted as i
  full join deleted as d
    on i.id = d.id
 where i.id=i1.id
 for xml path('row'), root('rows')
)
from inserted i1
UNION 
SELECT i1.id, (
 select *
 from inserted as i
  full join deleted as d
    on i.id = d.id
 where d.id=d1.id
 for xml path('row'), root('rows')
)
from deleted d1
```